# How to parse Uint8Array into object?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a message `payload` that I'd like to parse arbitrarily.  First two bytes go to int16's, next one a float32, last two are uint8's, etc.  It's a serialized structure.

There doesn't seem to be a clear way to go about this in Javascript.  In C, I could cast this as a certain type of struct and then get access to everything via dot notation.

Is there a library to easily manage this kind of binary conversation?  I'm thinking of some kind of parallel to python's [construct](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/construct/2.5.2) library?

Comment: Are you asking about how to implement such (I think you're looking for [`DataView`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView)), or looking for full-fledged libraries that allow declarative parsing like the `construct` you mentioned?

Comment: I'm asking how to implement, with the hope that someone would use a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typed arrays offers quite a variety of functions to decode easily a buffer.

tutorial
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/

spec :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Shortly, you have two ways to access a buffer :

1) You can create an ArrayBuffer access it with accessors through a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) : 
you can use then use the getInt( position) or getFloat32(position) to retrieve a given int/float at an arbitrary position.

(example from html5Rocks)

```
var dv = new DataView(buffer);
var vector_length = dv.getUint8(0);
var width = dv.getUint16(1); // 0+uint8 = 1 bytes offset
var height = dv.getUint16(3); // 0+uint8+uint16 = 3 bytes offset
var vectors = new Float32Array(width*height*vector_length);
for (var i=0, off=5; i<vectors.length; i++, off+=4) {
  vectors[i] = dv.getFloat32(off);
}
```

Or 2) You can access a whole part of that buffer that contains an Array by using the complete constructor of each typed Array :

```
   var view = new *someTypedArray*(buffer, byteOffset, length)
```

This way you can access easily to whole coherent parts of the stream.

( Where someTypedArray can be either :

```
Float64Array, Float32Array, Int32Array, Int16Array, Int8Array, 
 Uint32Array, Uint16Array, Uint8Array, Uint8ClampedArray
```

)